# Basic help needed with pointers (double indirection)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax

I asked some time ago on an account I can't remember how to manipulate basic pointers and someone gave me a really good demo

for example

```
char *ptr = "hello" (hello = a char array)
```

so now `*ptr` is pointing at 'h'

`ptr++` means moving the `ptr` to point at the next element, to get its value I do `*ptr` and that gives me `e`

---

ok so far everything works as I hope :D, but now I need to manipulate a `char **ptr` and was wondering how I do this in a way that mimics the effects of a 2d array?

Some basic tips would be much appreciated as I need to do an assignment that has a `**ptr` to imitate a 2d array and without knowing how it does this first means I can't even solve it on paper (for example, how do you dereference a `**ptr`, how do you get `[x][y]` values etc)

thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can subscript a pointer the same way you can subscript an array, provided all the addresses have been set up correctly.

Assuming the following declaration:

```
char **ptr;
```

here are the types of the various expressions:

```
       Expression        Type      Equivalent expressions (yield same value)     
       ----------        ----      -----------------------------------------
              ptr        char **   &ptr[0]
             *ptr        char *    ptr[0] 
         *(ptr+i)        char *    ptr[i]; &ptr[i][0]
            **ptr        char      ptr[0][0]
      *(*(ptr+i))        char      ptr[i][0]; *ptr[i]
    *(*(ptr+i)+j)        char      ptr[i][j]
```

thus:

- `ptr` can be treated *as though* it was an array of strings (2-d array of char)
- `ptr[i]` points to the beginning of the i'th string in the list
- `ptr[i][j]` is the value of the j'th character of the i'th string in the list
- The expressions `ptr++` and `++ptr` will advance `ptr` to point to the next string
- The expressions `(*ptr)++` and `++(*ptr)` will advance `*ptr` to point to the next character

As for setting up your pointers, this arrangement assumes everything has already been allocated as static arrays or dynamically through `malloc`.  You cannot just write

```
char **ptr = {"foo", "bar", "bletch"}; // using aggregate initializer on 
                                       // non-aggregate type; bad juju,
                                       // a.k.a undefined behavior
```

or

```
char **ptr;          // ptr has not been initialized to point anywhere 
ptr[0] = "foo";      // dereferencing ptr via subscript invokes undefined
ptr[1] = "bar";      // behavior
ptr[2] = "bletch";
```

Generally, when you're using a pointer as though it was an array, you'll use `malloc` or something similar to allocate your buffers:

```
char **ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * N);
if (ptr)
{
  ptr[0] = "foo";    // ptr[i] gets address of
  ptr[1] = "bar";    // string literal
  ptr[2] = "bletch";
  ...
}
```

or

```
char **ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * N);
if (ptr)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof *ptr[i] * M); // strictly speaking, the sizeof
    if (ptr[i])                          // is not necessary here
    {
      //initialize ptr[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, however "`ptr` and `ptr[0]` both point to the beginning of the first string in the list" is incorrect. Unlike the case with 2D arrays (which are contiguous across all their dimensions), `ptr` does not point to the same place as `ptr[0]`.

Comment: To make your first example work: `char* ary[] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch"};  char** ptr = &ary[0];`  This would declare `ptr` as a "pointer-to-array" and since each array element is a string (which is itself an array), `ptr` is in essence a "pointer-to-array-of-arrays".  Be careful when doing a double-dereference with this type of `char**` pointer; since the strings aren't the same length, you'll want to make certain you perform all necessary bounds checking.

Comment: @Max - you are correct (had arrays on the brain for some reason).  I've removed that statement.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: How does double indirection gets saved in the memory?

Answer (score 4):

A pointer to a pointer is just that. For example:

```
// Declare our double-indirection pointer.
char** ptr;
// And initialize it:
char s1[] = "hello";
char s2[] = "world";
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
ptr[0] = s1;
ptr[1] = s2;
// ptr now points to a pointer that points to 'h'.
char* ptr2 = *ptr;
// ptr2 points to 'h'.
char* ptr3 = *(ptr + 1);
// ptr3 points to "w".
char c = **ptr; // could be written as *(*ptr)
// c = 'h'.
char c2 = *(*(ptr + 1));
// c2 = 'w'.
char c3 = *(*(ptr) + 1);
// c3 = 'e'.
```

Comment: gcc throws up wome warnings on that first line (initialization from incompatible pointer type, excess elements in scalar initializer).  You're using an array initializer on a non-array type.

Answer (score 1):

You may use them as you would a normal two-dimensional array. (Since effectively, that's what they are)

```
char** ptr = {"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"};
char* s1 = ptr[0]; //Points to the beginning of "lorem"
char* s2 = ptr[1]; //Points to the beginning of "ipsum"
char c = ptr[2][4]; //Contains 'r'
```

This is due to the fact that:

```
int *a;
//...
int i = a[6];
int j = *(a + 6); //Same as previous line!
```

Cheers,

Amit Ron--